# Proving $m^2+pm+q=0$, $p,q>0\in Z$, have only negative roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can you prove that the equation $m^2+pm+q=0$, for $m\in \Re$ and $p,q>0\in Z$ have only negative real solutions if $p^2-4q>0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula? Write down the roots of this equation using that formula.

Comment: do you mean "$m\in \mathbb R$" ?

Comment: With only the quadratic formula how can you tell that the root is negative? You somehow would need to show that $-p \pm \sqrt {p^2-4q} <0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$p^2-4q$$ is the so-called discriminant. If it is positive, both roots are real and distinct.

If moreover $$p,q>0$$ holds, the real roots can obviously not be non-negative, since $$m^2+pm+q$$ is obviously positive for $\ m\ge 0\ $. Hence we have two distinct real negative roots.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

The vertex of the parabola is at $-\frac{p}{2}$ which is negative . The graph cuts y axis at q which is positive. I think that's enough to show that roots are negative.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't think of a geometric proof.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the discriminant is positive implies that there are two distinct real roots. The sum of the roots is $\frac{-p}{2}$ which is negative. Thus at least one of the roots is negative. The product of the roots is $q$ which is positive. Hence both roots are negative.